# IXMLDocument.SaveToFile() uses tab character for indentation instead of spaces

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-2010, indentation, auto-indent

I have an XML file, which is originally formatted using space indents (2 spaces for each nested item).

When I load and save this file using IXMLDocument, space indents are changing to the tab characters (code #9).

Here is the code:

```
 var
   FileName: String;
   Document: IXMLDocument;
 ...
 Document := XMLDoc.LoadXMLDocument(FileName);
 Document.SaveToFile(FileName);
```

I tried to use `NodeIndentStr` property - no result:

```
 Document := XMLDoc.LoadXMLDocument(FileName);
 Document.NodeIndentStr := '  ';
 Document.SaveToFile(FileName);
```

Used `FormatXMLData` too - no result:

```
 Document := XMLDoc.LoadXMLDocument(FileName);
 Document.XML.Text := XMLDoc.FormatXMLData(Document.XML.Text);
 Document.Active := True;
 Document.SaveToFile(FileName);
```

How can I save with space indents instead of tab characters?

Comment: You might want to read this article by Zarko Gajic, [delphi-format-xml-node-indent](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2009/qt/delphi-format-xml-node-indent.htm). The solution provided uses `xmlDoc.FormatXMLData` to format the file in a nice way.

Comment: I see where's the problem lies now, the `FormatXMLData` has no chance to know what `NodeIndentStr` are you using since you are passing a string to that function, thus it uses the default TAB char.

Comment: @TLama so what's the solution?

Comment: Have you tried to use `preserveWhiteSpace` (`IXMLDOMDocument`)?

Comment: There is an option `poPreserveWhiteSpace`. Used like this: `Document.ParseOptions := 
Document.ParseOptions+[poValidateOnParse]+[poPreserveWhiteSpace];`. Does that do the job ?, Sorry Kobik, just saw your comment.

Comment: @LURD, Don't be :) actually you need to post this as answer (if it works) since I was referring to `IXMLDOMDocument`. and I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an option in `IXMLDocument` where the parser can be told to preserve white spaces.

Use it like this :

```
Document.ParseOptions := 
  Document.ParseOptions+[poValidateOnParse]+[poPreserveWhiteSpace];
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tried it.

Comment: +1. I'm on D5 now, and can't test it with newer versions of Delphi, but if the `IXMLDocument` is a wrapper around `IXMLDOMDocument` this should work (tested with `IXMLDOMDocument`).

Comment: yes, it works. Thank you. Note: `ParseOptions` should be set before `LoadFromFile()`

Comment: +1 from me too. This do the trick. Maybe would be fine to mention there's no need to use `NodeIndentStr` nor `doNodeAutoIndent` option since you are passing string to the `FormatXMLData` function (not document itself), thus it has it's own settings. And you can remove the `poValidateOnParse` flag ;-)

Comment: @Andrew, might be, but better to say before `Document.XML.Text` where you are assigning the new XML document which is being parsed.

Comment: And you can shorten the options assignment like this: `Document.ParseOptions + [poValidateOnParse, poPreserveWhiteSpace];', removing a pair of brackets. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is different but *Document.ParseOptions + [poValidateOnParse, poPreserveWhiteSpace];* was not accessible for me.

Something similar worked:

```
var
    xmlDoc: IXMLDOMDocument2;

xmlDoc := CreateOleObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM') as IXMLDOMDocument2;
xmlDoc.validateOnParse := True;
xmlDoc.preserveWhiteSpace := True;
```